# How to set tool.poetry.source as environment variable

Tags: python, python-poetry, toml

I'm using Poetry with a private repo and need to know if there is a way to set the following config in `pyproject.toml` as env variable. The Poetry [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#using-environment-variables) says something like `export POETRY_TOOL_POETRY_SOURCE_NAME=repo` should work but I had no luck make it work.

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "repo"
url = "https://a.url/simple"
```

Comment: I think you can only set the config settings available here https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#available-settings